# YSlow score me low on external URLs' expiry

Tags: seo, external, yslow

When perfoming YSlow check, I get the following:

```
Add Expires headers 
C (78)    SERVER    HIGH

There are 2 static components without a far-future expiration date.

http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700
http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js
```

How can I improve my score or at least remove these from the list?

Answer (score 0):

You can't optimized any external links, but for the Javascript file its recommended to load them at the end of the document before the ending  tag.